# Member Email System

Tags: members, email, member-management

I'm developing a membership website wherein members should be able to email each other. I do not plan to expose EE's admin to the members. Instead, they will be using a custom built "profile manager." In this profile manager, is there a way I can tap into EE's email system so that I can let my members email each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use Messaging module (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/messaging) which works great.